# Error while connecting Google Analytics with Search Console

Tags: search, google-analytics, console, google-search-console

I am trying to connect Google Analytics with Search Console but getting the below error:

"Hm. Something isn't right. We're checking into it now."

Screenshot - https://drops.meetanshi.com/rAq8Kt

Please help me with the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Quite a few people are experiencing this issue, which indicates it's a problem on Google's side.

Comment: Google are aware of the issue and are looking into it.